# Add navigation from tag info page(s) to tag badges

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-badges

Every row in the [list of tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) has a link to the relevant tag. But there is no corresponding reverse link; indeed, there are no links to or even *mentions* of tag badges anywhere in the specific pages for a tag, not even on [the top users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/topusers)!

Currently, tag badges don't have particularly good visibility (you have to first go to [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) and then notice the *highly* unobtrusive 'tags' link). I suggest it would be a Good Idea to have navigation from at least one of the per-tag pages to the tag badges.

[image]